# Resize capacity of List<T>

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, list, memory-management

I read the source code of the class `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` of .NET4.0 with Reflector,
and I have some questions.
Here is the code:

```
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (this._size == this._items.Length)
        {
            this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);
        }
        this._items[this._size++] = item;
        this._version++;
    }
    private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
    {
        if (this._items.Length < min)
        {
            int num = (this._items.Length == 0) ? 4 : (this._items.Length * 2);
            if (num > 0x7fefffff)
            {
                num = 0x7fefffff;
            }
            if (num < min)
            {
                num = min;
            }
            this.Capacity = num;
        }
    }
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public int Capacity
    {
        // omitted code

        set
        {
            if (value < this._size)
            {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.value, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_SmallCapacity);
            }
            if (value != this._items.Length)
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    T[] destinationArray = new T[value];
                    if (this._size > 0)
                    {
                        Array.Copy(this._items, 0, destinationArray, 0, this._size);
                    }
                    this._items = destinationArray;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._items = List<T>._emptyArray;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- Is it the best way or the only way to resize the array by copying all elements to a new array?
- Why check the "num" with "0x7fefffff"? Why "0x7fefffff" is special?
- Why they can use "4" and "0x7fefffff" directly? Aren't they magic numbers?

  Thanks.

Comment: As a note to other people answering this: `0x7fefffff` = `2146435071` = `2^31`

Comment: Wiki says to do it like that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array. For first question.

Comment: @AdamKewley Actually 2^31 = 2147483648.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes sorry, I was rounding the number to the nearest integer. However, computational systems will want a *literal* interpretation of it, my bad.

Comment: My EnsureCapacity is different from yours, I don't see the check against *0x7fefffff*, what version of .Net are you on?

Comment: Thank you @SriramSakthivel, I'll read it carefully.

Comment: I'm a little surprised `List<T>` is implemented much like an `std::vector` though so this is news for me. I naively assumed it was implemented as a linked list.

Comment: @JMK I'm on .Net 4.0.

Comment: @Chris Weird, so am I, how are you viewing the code?

Comment: @AdamKewley: `2^31 = 0x80000000`. On the other hand `2^31 - 2^20 - 1 = 0x7feffffff`.

Comment: @JMK Reflector,of course.

Comment: Hm, Dotpeek from Jetbrains doesn't show that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it the best way or the only way to resize the array by copying all elements to a new array?

Yes, that's the only way to resize an array.

For a given size array, only that section of memory is allocated for the array, the surrounding memory could be allocated to other things, so you can't simply expand the memory, you need a bigger slot.

> Why check the "num" with "0x7fefffff"? Why "0x7fefffff" is special?

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array(v=vs.110).aspx):

> However, the array will still be limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to **a maximum index of 0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension** (0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures).

I couldn't find any documentation to indicate *why* 0X7FEFFFFF is the maximum allowed size though (they probably have some decent good reasons for such a limit).

> Why they can use "4" and "0x7fefffff" directly? Aren't they magic numbers?

`const`'s probably would've made sense here.

This may not be *exactly* what the original code looks like (as [usr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr) mentions, it could've been decompiled), so there indeed could've been `const`'s used.

If it happens to be what the original code looks like, I'm sure only the developers can tell you why they did what they did.

Comment: The code looks decompiled. They probably *were* constants once.

Comment: `Constant variables` is a oxymoron. :) and as @usr pointed they might be `constants` reflector shows as hard coded values :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the original source (for .NET 4.0, I believe):

```
    // Ensures that the capacity of this list is at least the given minimum 
    // value. If the currect capacity of the list is less than min, the
    // capacity is increased to twice the current capacity or to min, 
    // whichever is larger. 
    private void EnsureCapacity(int min) {
        if (_items.Length < min) { 
            int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
            // Allow the list to grow to maximum possible capacity (~2G elements) before encountering overflow.
            // Note that this check works even when _items.Length overflowed thanks to the (uint) cast
            if ((uint)newCapacity > Array.MaxArrayLength) newCapacity = Array.MaxArrayLength; 
            if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min;
            Capacity = newCapacity; 
        } 
    }
```

As for your questions:

- Yes, you can't resize an existing array. However, [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) allows you to do what `List.Capacity` does, but in less code. It creates the new array, copies elements, and assigns the new array for you.
- If you look at the original code, it becomes clear that the limit is the size of arrays in the CLR. It looks like arrays can be up to `int.MaxValue` elements long, minus 0x100000 slots, possibly for array overhead. I can't really say what specifically those slots are for.
- In the original code, they are constants. The C# compiler doesn't compile references to constants. It only stores the value. This is why constants become magic numbers in decompiled code.